# Can't get transition to work for accordion menu

Tags: javascript, menu, comments, accordion

I'm having a problem where I want to have an accordion menu that automatically expands to fit content that is dynamically added. I want the accordion body to expand its height to accommodate more comments as they are added. The accordion works, but it will not take a transition.

Can somebody assist me with what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```js
const accordionItemHeader = document.querySelector(".accordionItemHeader");
 
  accordionItemHeader.addEventListener("click", event => {
  accordionItemHeader.classList.toggle("active");

  const accordionItemBody = document.querySelector(".accordionItemBody");

    if (accordionItemHeader.classList.contains("active")) {
      accordionItemBody.style.setProperty("max-height", "100%");
    } else {
      accordionItemBody.style.setProperty("max-height", "0");
    }
  })
```

```css
.accordionItemHeader {
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    background-color: $spruce;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
      h5 {
        color: $iceBlue;
      }
  }


  .accordionItemHeader::after, .accordionItemHeader.active::after {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%; 
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: $iceBlue;
  }

  .accordionItemHeader::after {
    content: "\25BC";
  }

  .accordionItemHeader.active::after {
    content: "\25B2";   
  }
  
  .accordionContent {
    padding: 10px;
    
  }

  .accordionItemBody {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px $spruce solid;
    padding: 0;
    // transition: max-height 0.5s; <-- this is what won't work
  }
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordionItem">
    <div class="accordionItemHeader">
      <h5>Comments</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="accordionItemBody">
      <div class="accordionContent">
        <ul class="commentsPosted">
          <!--dynamic comments posted go here-->
          <li class="placeholderComment">
            <p>No comments yet</p>
          </li>
        </ul>    
      </div><!--accordionContent div end -->
    </div> <!--accordionitembody div end-->
  </div><!--accordionItem div end-->
</div><!--accordion div end-->
```

Comment: this is very much like a simple accordion from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Comment: Yes it works when the content in the accordion is static. However, I am using this for a comments section where it is expected to dynamically enlarge as new comments are added. I have succeeded in getting it to resize automatically but the transition refuses to work when I place it in the CSS